# Combining multiple sql statements

Tags: sql

I have two tables. Let's call them `weapons` and `weapon_powers`.

- `Weapons` has `ID` (primary)
- `weapon powers` has `ID` (primary) and `WEAPONTYPE`.

`WEAPONTYPE` is the `ID` of the weapon the power is assigned to.

A power equipped on weapon 1 would have a `weapontype` of 1.

How do I combine these two statements into one?

```
select * from weapons where ID = somevariable

select * from weapon_powers where WEAPONTYPE = somevariable
```

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"? What output do you want?

Comment: I want every record from the first table who's id matches the variable and I also want every record from teh second table who's weapons type also matches that same variable  Also I am a mysql noob.

Comment: What's wrong with the output you get from executing both statements separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading your description right, it looks like you have:

```
WEAPONS   <------->0..*   WEAPON_POWERS
-------                   -------------
ID (PK)                   ? (PK)
...                       WEAPONTYPE (FK WEAPONS(ID))
                          ...
```

In that case I think you just want a join:

```
SELECT *
FROM weapons
LEFT OUTER JOIN weapon_powers ON weapons.ID = weapon_powers.WEAPONTYPE
WHERE weapons.ID = @somevariable
```

This query will return all powers equipped for the given weapon, or a single row with data from `weapons` and `NULL` for the `weapon_powers.*` columns if there are no powers equipped.